# How to access parent from child in datagrid wpf?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I am currently working on a `WPF` application with a Datagrid in it.
I have 3 classes, Parent class, Child Class and a GrandChild Class. 
(Parent has a collection of Child. Child has a collection of GrandChild).
`DataContext` for the window is set to Parent. 
Datagrid's item source is set to GrandChild.
There is a checkbox in the main window whose IsChecked property is bind to the Parent Class.

Now one of the datagrid column's visibility depends on this checkbox. If the checkbox is checked the column will be collapsed.

How to bind the Parent property to the `DataGridTextColumn`'s visibility property (I have implemented the visibility converter)?

Here is the sample scenario

```
public class TableViewModel
{
public TableViewModel()
{
  PopulateTables();
}

public  ObservableCollection<Table> Tables { get; set; }

public Table SelectedItem { get; set; }

}

Public class Table{

public string TableName { get; set; }

public bool HasHeaders { get; set; }

public ObservableCollection<Column> Columns { get; set; }

}

public class Column{

public string HeaderText { get; set; }
public int Width { get; set; }
public int Height { get; set; }
}
```

### TblManager.xaml.cs

```
public partial class TblManager : Window
{
    public TblManager()
        {
            InitializeComponent();  

            this.DataContext = new TableViewModel();                       
        }
}
```

### TblManager.xaml

```
<Grid>
<ListBox Name="lstTables" ItemsSource="{Binding path=Tables}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem}" Width="160" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TableName}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>   

<GroupBox Name="grpProperties" Header="Properties" Width="150" Height="170" Margin="167,0,0,31" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
   <Grid Margin="0,5,0,0">
      <CheckBox Name="chkRemoveHeaderRow" Content="Remove Header Row" IsChecked="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.HasHeaders, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"  />
    </Grid>
</GroupBox>

<GroupBox Name="grpColumns" Header="Columns" Width="220" Height="170" Margin="311,0,0,30" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
  <DataGrid Name="dgTable"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Columns}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False"   HeadersVisibility="Column" SelectionMode="Single">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="Headers" Width="80" Binding="{Binding Path=HeaderText,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Visibility="{Binding XXXXXXXXXXXXXX}" />
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="Width" Width="60" Binding="{Binding Path=Width, Converter={StaticResource SwapConverter}, ConverterParameter=TableColWidth,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  />
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="Height" Width="60" Binding="{Binding Path=Height, Converter={StaticResource SwapConverter}, ConverterParameter=TableColWidth,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  />
     </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

How to bind the "Remove Header Row" checkbox HasHeaders property to DataGridTextColumn's Visibility property?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide us with a [mcve] so we could answer your question. Also, please take a look on [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to get familiar with how to ask a good question.

Comment: Is it the checkbox which controls the visibility or is it a property in the parent class ? If it is the checkbox, there is no need to use the Parent class to control the visibility. If the parent class is controlling the visibility, why do you talk about the checkbox ?

Comment: Hi Peter, I have a listbox which has a list of tables. Each table has a boolean property HasHeaders and list of columns. If the HasHeaders is false, datagrid should not show the first datagridtextcolumn which is the headers column